# How to read following data and construct into JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have some log file which has following sample data stored in it like this. The file is generated using some other program where it keeps appending such lines to the file.

```
{ 'Temperature' : 53.375 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416429462 }
{ 'Temperature' : 53.385 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416459464 }
.
.
and so on...
```

Well, i wrote something like this to get the values. This is just an example

```
var result =[{ 'Temperature' : 53.375 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416429462 }];
$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    for(var attribute in v){
        if(v.hasOwnProperty(attribute)){
            alert(attribute + ' is ' + v[attribute]);
        }
    }
});
```

My question is how do I read file line by line and generate JSON output out of it? 
The output should look something like this

```
{
    "city": [
        {
            "Temperature": 53.375,
            "Timestamp": 1416429462
        },
        {
            "Temperature": 53.385,
            "Timestamp": 1416459464
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not much experienced with JQuery so I honestly don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little dirty but worth trying. Applicable to your situation

```
//Assuming this is the content of the file
var q = "{ 'Temperature' : 53.375 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416429462 }{ 'Temperature' : 53.385 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416459464 }"


q = replaceAll(q,"'","\"");
q = replaceAll(q,"}, {",",");
q = replaceAll(q,"}{","},{");
//Instead of above line you may have to try this below variation. Which considers a new line character
q = replaceAll(q,"}\n{","},{");
q = "{\"City\":["+q+"]}";

//An alert for you to see what your string looks like now
alert(q);
// this is the final Json object
var result = $.parseJSON(q)

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  var i = str.indexOf(find);
  if (i > -1){
    str = str.replace(find, replace); 
    i = i + replace.length;
    var st2 = str.substring(i);
    if(st2.indexOf(find) > -1){
      str = str.substring(0,i) + replaceAll(st2, find, replace);
    }       
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Oh nice! but it may not be suitable solution for very large data right? Anyhow this does solve the problem hence I am accepting this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into multi dimensional array format and use JSON.stringify to format it to json

```
var result =[{ 'Temperature' : 53.375 }, { 'Timestamp' : 1416429462 }];
var data = {"city" : result};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(json);
```

Comment: But the output is coming out little different than what is desired. 
```{
    "city": [
        {
            "Temperature": 53.375
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": 1416429462
        },
        {
            "Temperature": 53.385
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": 1416459464
        }
    ]
}``` Look at the output (Mentioned in the question) that I want.